# CSS - Selector for selecting specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form.
I'd like all the '*' marks in the placeholders to be red.
I don't care if it changes all then '*' in the whole body, I'm not using them elsewhere.
Of course I could do it with *,
but it'd just make my code look messier than ever, and there's gotta be a more compact way.

I tried this jQuery in ´head´ and ´body´ , but it didn't work:

```
     jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {    
            var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

            return this.each(function () {
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
        });
    };
     $("input").highlight("*","highlight");
```

Here's a piece of my form:

```
 <input type="text" class="text" name="phone" placeholder="*Puhelin" />
```

Comment: css can't target characters. characters in a placeholder can't be individually styled. characters in an input can't be individually styled.

Comment: The problem arises because you are using the `placeholder` attribute instead of a label. HTML5 CR says: “The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a label.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to style that individual character within an attribute, or even style an individual character within an input.

However, there is a way to accomplish this.

Make the background of your input transparent and place an element behind the input that will hold your placeholder. Now, all you have to do is wrap the `*` character in a span and style it to be red, then show and hide the placeholder element as needed.

proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Ay45T/

This will also allow the placeholder to work in older browsers since it doesn't rely on the built-in placeholder.

Comment: This solution is much more complicated than my CSS one, but if this is a must-have feature that you need in older browsers you are going to have to do it this way.

Comment: I was under the impression he wanted to color a single character, not the whole placeholder. I prefer doing it this way though because it also could make translating the text much easier.

Comment: I thought he just mentioned `*` as a CSS selector. If he wants just that character red, my CSS solution is definitely not going to work. Aaand the OP has clarified that is what he wants, so I am going to remove my answer.

Comment: well, i corrected a mistake in his question. the markdown syntax was converting his '\*' to '*'*

Comment: Not quite working on my code. I guess I did something wrong. JSFiddle seems to hate my form, tho it works fine here: http://artotek.fi JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ay45T/3/